# Validation in spring boot rest controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

Is there any  library available for validation similar  in java  similar to FluentValidation  for .Net  for  rest controller data validation?

Comment: Library recommendations are off topic per the [help].

Comment: Sorry I was not aware about.

Answer (score 2):

The most widely used validation api with spring boot is - `javax-validation-api` - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final

Answer (score -1):

You can use bean validation in spring-boot

https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

This is base on JSR303 where you can annotate Pojo fields with validation and values are validated in the controller layer before processing.